# Can I fix the disappearing mouse pointer in Nautilus when opening a new folder? (18.04)

Tags: nautilus, mouse

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, I had problems with Nautilus as the mouse disappear while Nautilus reads a folder I just opened. Once read, the mouse pointer comes back as normal.

Is this a new feature? It's really annoying since the nautilus window is usable immediately, while the read is happening, so I'd like the mouse to stay visible as it makes it a lot easier to aim at the icons...

Is there an option to choose whether the mouse gets hidden while loading a folder?